# VB.net render PDF format, and control PDF object

Tags: vb.net, pdf, pdf-generation

I want to manage PDF format document in VB.net project.

I want to render PDF document in the Form, 
and extract objects in the PDF.

It means that the color of the text(string), size of the text and font name of the text could be changed by the app, moreover,
size of the shape and pictures(stream) also could be changed.

Is it possible to do that without Acrobat or third-party component?

If it is too difficult to do it without components, then

Is there any free-for-commercial component to manage those feature?

Thanks a lot!

---

plus,
there are many free PDF viewers on the Internet. are they using their own PDF rendering component or just adopting existing PDF components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieve with the help of 3rd party components. I use GD Picture for PDF manipulation, but it's not free by any means and is great. Others include iTextSharp, PDFSharp and ABCPdf; each having their pros and cons...